# Use two MouseListeners at "one time"

Tags: java, swing, grid, jlabel, mouselistener

Let's they I have a 2x2 grid made with 4 JLabels. I want to display the content of the JLabel (a String) when clicking on a field and other content, when releasing the mouse on an other field (or the same when releasing on the same field).

In my for clause which is giving the coordinates to each fields (x;y) I can use the actual position while using this loops to create the coordinates

```
for (int y = s - 1; y >= 0; y--) { //starting with int s,v = 2
for (int x = 0; x < v; x++) {
  field[x][y] = new JLabel((x) + ";" + (y));
  field[x][y].setName((x) + ";" + (y));
```

adding a Listener to it with

```
field[x][y].addMouseListener(new myMouseListener());
```

and get the setName() like this in my class mousePressed

```
Component c = e.getComponent();
sysout(c.getName());
```

...same thing in mouseReleased

```
d = e.getComponent();
System.out.println(d.getName());
```

In the theory I should get different coordinates when releasing the mouse, but I always get the same ones as while pressing the mouse.

For example: c.getName() return 3;2 AND d.getName() return 3;2

How can i change this?

Comment: Wait.. why would you use JLabel as a clickable component?

Comment: Because I'm trying to code a game and want to display icon in it etc pp.

Comment: And what is a reason not to use JButton?

Comment: I've no reason to switch, I've already set everything up. I just want to know if there is a way to get my problem solved. What are the advantages of JButton?

Answer (score 1):

More less, this demo shows how to solve your problem:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JLabelsDemo {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel[][] label = new JLabel[2][2];
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10);

    public JLabelsDemo() {

        frame.setLayout(gridLayout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                label[i][j] = new JLabel("");
                label[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                label[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
                final String msg = "JLabel " + i + "," + j;
                label[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
                    }

                });
                frame.add(label[i][j]);
            }

        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(320, 240);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JLabelsDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But still, my recommendation is not to use `JLabels` as a clickable components. Instead, use JButtons because of easier implementation of event listener.

Comment: I think you misunterstood me. I want no coordinate when clicking on a JField, only when clicking on a JField and releasing the mouse on a different(!) JField. The output should be something like 3;3 - 3;1 as i mentioned in my first posting. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Anyway, it would be a big help if you could just show me how to get coordinates when releasing the mouse.